# How to identify Sliver triangles in a TIN surface and count them?

Tags: tin, slivers, delaunay

Is it possible to count slivers in a TIN?

I generated a Delaunay triangulation surface model and i want to know how many slivers the TIN has.

Comment: Maybe you could edit your question to say how you made your TINs, which methods you used and how they're represented, so people can give concrete answers.

Comment: What GIS software are you using to try and do this?

Comment: A sliver is a gap or extra polygon along what should be a continuous shared edge between two polygons. Theoretically a TIN wouldn't have any slivers. Are you wanting a count of the triangular faces that make up the TIN?

Answer (score 0):

You could

1. create a "world" layer, i.e. a polygon covering your area
2. do a Clip between the world polygon and your TIN
3. extract/select polygons with a narrow area (you have to define you threshold area value)

This could lead to the selection of small polygons not being a sliver, but it wil match most of your cases. Otherwise you could restrict the selection calculating a [shape factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape_factor_(image_analysis_and_microscopy)) (maybe circularity could be enough), which will help in selecting elongated polygons.

In QGIS this can be done easily using Processing -> QGIS Geoalgorithms -> Intersection for point 2), and doing a Select by expression using the $area function.